# SSH "Could not open input file: bin/magento" Magento2

Tags: magento2, ssh

Yesterday I was working on my new Magento2 site and add new module after that I use SSH command and it was working perfectly but today morning I start working and start putty to run command but it's not working. if I run any command it's show me error that `could not open input file : bin/magento`.

First I run command  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` also I run command related cache , indexing but same error I get all the time.

can anyone tell me why is it happening ? and how to solve this error message?

I checked in magento root folder that there is bin folder and within bin folder there is magento file.

Comment: Please check ssh user and sftp  user are different ?

Comment: @AmitBera that is not a issue because I was working yesterday using same username and password.

Comment: As per as,my concept it may permission issue for user. Try to give excute permission to` bin/magento` by `find -L vendor/bin -type f -exec chmod u+x {} \;`

Comment: revert the module and check again because I met the same issue while made mistake in registration.php (wrong module name).

Comment: Also , Disable your module and  run code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what have you done after adding some new code but i guess this is the issue cause your new code is not compiled. I am writing some command you should run after adding new code.

Go to the root folder of your Magento project and run the following commands :

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo chmod 777 -R var/
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue on windows and solved it by this command instead:

```
php bin\\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I doubled the `\` to `\\`

Comment: not sure why, but it worked

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same problem. But  I was inside bin and typing

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But instead of that I should type

```
php magento setup:upgrade
```

**(NOTE: no bin required).**

So check the path where you are in and point to bin folder magento file.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. First of all you need to CD your magento installation direcotry. For example `cd /my/magento/installation/directory` and then run the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`;

Comment: This can also be done in the bin folder

Comment: No need to go in bin folder.. It happens due to chache..
Just you have to delete sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di
then run your all commands..It solves the issue.