# Upgrading to 2.2.3 /bin is then empty

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, bin-magento

I want to upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 and I ran the following commands

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
composer update
```

Then when I try to do

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I get "Could not open input file: bin/magento"

When I look it seems as though both files (.htaccess and magento) have been deleted.

Could anyone advise?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118347/ssh-could-not-open-input-file-bin-magento-magento2

Comment: Seem that it's a permission issue.

Comment: I dont think it is a permission issue though as the files physically don't exist after trying to upgrade. They did exist before the upgrade