# How to Run the Command 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade' As a CLI Application

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.3

When I run the command '/usr/local/php71/bin/php-cli /home/******/public_html/bin/magentosetup:upgrade'
on a siteground.com hosted site with Magento 2.3.0 installed it worked perfectly

But on an inmotionhosting.com hosted site with Magento 2.3.3 installed it returned the error 'no such file or directory'

Please help

[image]

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade -h run this command ..

Comment: I tried 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade -h'      it returned the error: 'could not open input file: bin/magento'

Comment: Please send screen shot

Comment: I have added a screenshot, you can view it above. Thank you

Comment: Please refer this links :-  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118347/ssh-could-not-open-input-file-bin-magento-magento2 2> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Could-not-open-input-file-bin-magento/td-p/112857 And  conform command run properly root

Comment: Thank you so much, It was a syntax error, I corrected it! Gracias!

Comment: okay solve issues ??